# Make a div-row collapse in html/css/django

Tags: html, css, django

I have recently designed a really small django template looking like this :

[image: Example]

The html code looks like this :

```
  {% for category in categories %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <h3>{{ category }}</h3>
        <ul>
          {% for elem in elems %}
            <li><a href=...>{{ elem }}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

And the CSS code :

```
.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}    

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.column{
  width: 50%; 
}
```

I would like to have the rows to collapse if there is enough space.
In my example, I would like the Test column to go just behind the Pet one (only separated by the padding).
Is there any css property which could help me achieving this ? Or should I change my approach ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divs have no defined width. They will take up the entire page such that there is no horizontal room left. What you want is a responsive design that changes that width based on the size of the boxes, and the size of the screen.

Using the @media selector to limit a specific style to the size of the current browser window will allow the size of the divs to respond as you desire:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 600px) {
   .box {
      width: 50%;

   }
}
@media screen and (min-width : 601px) {
   .box {
      width: 33.3%;
   }
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puuw9y55/)

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Having read your comments I now see what you mean. Saying collapse confused me and I assumed you were asking for something dynamic.

The best way to solve this is to prioritise columns over rows. It's not a true table so they aren't even rows exactly.

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Drinks</h3>
        <ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Food</h3>
        <ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Pet</h3>
        <ul><li>item 1</li></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the following CSS will give the desired result.

```
.column {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

Using your code this would equate to:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <div class="column">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>{{ category }}</h3>
            <ul> {% for elem in elems %}<li><a href=...> {{ elem }}</a></li>{% endfor %}</ul>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This answer has gotten quite long, I apologise!

[New JS FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhx45uvd/)

Comment: Unfortunately, by doing this, the number of columns could increase from 2 to 3, but I would like my rows to collapse, not my columns.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean. Could you give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Well, just see my picture above, it is simply to not have the row alligned, and have my test column just below the pet one.